Keyboard function keys stop working after resuming from sleep
I have this Microsoft keyboard with relevant software installed:

It is connected to the screen (LG 32UN88A-W) which itself is connected to the laptop using USB-C.
When computer resumes from sleep, the upper function keys stop working.
Only fix I've found is to re-connect it every single time...
Any idea on what could be causing this?
